# Do I have to subscribe for services such as Amazon S3 to use Filepicker?

Tags: amazon-s3, filepicker.io

Bit of a noob here. I was wondering if I have to subscribe to a cloud storage service to use filepicker.io.

Comment: More info needed, ehat exactly do you want?

Comment: https://www.filestack.com/pricing

If you go there they suggest unlimited file sizes, so my questing is, do they store the data I upload or do they want me to have a cloud storage such as Amazon S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to subscribe to S3 to use Filestack, however your app gets a lot more powerful if you do. Thanks to that, you can store your files directly to your storage so you will never lose access to them.  If you haven't put in your storage credentials your files will be stored on Filestack's server.